# How to make appium tests run faster on iOS?

Tags: java, ios, jenkins, appium

Currently, I am using appium for iOS app testing and I have written tests in Java on mac mini machine. I’m using Jenkins CI to run my tests. I want to run my tests faster as currently its quite slow on iOS simulator. For example, if I enter any value in textfield via sendkeys() function like ’testdata’ then typing speed in emulator is slow. It first write character ’t’ then ‘e’ then ’s’ and so on from simulator’s keyboard.

Following are my questions,

1. Is there any way I execute my tests faster on simulator specially
   when entering in textfields through sendkeys() function?
2. Is there any way I can run my tests without simulator in headless fashion?

Answer (score 9):

#### Don't use send keys on iOS

You're actually not supposed to use `sendKeys` on iOS because it's slow and flakey.

You're supposed to use `setValue` for the Java lib and `type` for the ruby lib

#### Set Value usage

`setValue` is defined in Java library [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/cbcdee8a1c742bac9f4c1ccd38a6e69863f96885/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.java#L68).

It is meant to be called on a WebElement.

```
driver.find_element(By.locator(value)).setValue("foo")
```

#### Using the iOS Simulator is the best option for running tests

A live simulator or real device* is required for Instruments to interact with your application. There are some best practices you can follow to improve your test code which will likely make the tests quicker.

#### Other best practices for optimization

1. Do not use "sleeps" to try and wait for an element -- instead constantly poll the driver for if the element is displayed and clickable.
2. Use `setValue`instead of sendKeys
3. Stop using Xpath locator strategy. It is flakey and slow on iOS. Use UIAutomation or AccessibilityId locator strategy.
4. Only get the elements when you need to interact with them

#### *Using Real Devices for iOS is not suggested (when performance matters)

Automating a real device has a builtin delay of one second between every action.

No matter how quick the Appium server is, or your test script is, there is a delay between when Appium pushes the "execute" command to the instruments work queue and when it is executed on the device.

Comment: In which library I can find setValue() function?
Currently, I'm using like this

webs.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath")).sendKeys(String);

where 'webs' is the webdriver object.

How can I replace this sendkeys() with setValue? I don't find any function like setValue() in WebDriver library.

Comment: `setValue` is defined [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/cbcdee8a1c742bac9f4c1ccd38a6e69863f96885/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.java#L68)

Comment: For appium's `ruby_lib` the method is called `type`, not `set_value`.

Comment: `You're actually not supposed to use sendKeys on iOS` source?

Comment: Original thread at the bottom. Each request to do or get something in an app goes from your client, through an Appium server, and finally to UIAutomation inside of Instruments. At the time, setValue would make 2 requests to UIAutomation to set "Hello world" on a UITextField. 1 request to get the text field element. 1 request to set the entire value. sendKeys will make 12. 1 for the text field element. 1 for each letter in "Hello world".  (https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-make-appium-tests-run-faster-on-ios/445/3)

Comment: To be noted: I haven't looked at Appium since 2014. If you want to know if the above is still the case, try doing this usecase, looking at the Appium server logs, and counting the network requests for each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

where can I find more info on this suggestion (I'm using ruby instead of java) and I xpath a lot which I guess might be one of the reasons scripts take too long to execute.

"Stop using Xpath locator strategy. It is flakey and slow on iOS. Use UIAutomation or AccessibilityId locator strategy."

Comment: Locator strategies have all the same problems in Appium as they do in Selenium Automation. The xpath locator strategy is flakey by design. If the structure of the UI changes, your tests break. It is slow because it needs to traverse the DOM to find the element, instead of looking up a unique ID (AccessibilityID). http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/17664/8116 and (skip to the bottom of this thread https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2639)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the iOS capability of sendKeyStrategy to setValue instead of the default of OneByOne.

Comment: I did try to use sendKeyStrategy but it seems it does not work. What i did capabilities.setCapability("sendKeyStrategy", "grouped"); but it did not work and appium continue writing oneByone. Any suggestion?