# How can I get element handles for testing my Cordova app with Appium?

Tags: ios, cordova, appium

I'm trying to test our Cordova app in Appium. I'm using the [node wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) interface. When I view the elements in the Appium Inspector, they don't seem to have anything that I can use as far as identifiers. For example, I see the following on my email text input for login:

[image: Appium Inspector view of text element]

I am setting various things in the HTML for this element, such as `id`, `name`, etc. (it also has a label that is using the `for` attribute that points to the input.) but it does not appear to have anything that I can look for. So I end up looking for `UIATextField` elements with *value* of Email. This is undesirable since I do not have a consistent way to look up inputs. For example, if I change the value of the input, I would need to look up the element by that new input.

So my question is: how can I set accessibility identifiers or any handles for this element from the HTML from Cordova? I would even take `data-*` attributes that I could query for. Or am I going about this incorrectly?

I ask about accessibility identifiers since I have read in other places that [I should not use XPath selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915967/how-to-make-appium-tests-run-faster-on-ios/25916190#25916190) for Appium tests, but I can see no clear reason why this is the case (it seems to work for me.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the context? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24878765/31252. Currently you are working on the UIAutomation layer, which is native iOS and doesn't know anything about your HTML but I am hoping when you switch to a webview context then you should be able to see your identifiers.

Changing context definetely works in webviews (android and iOS) but I am not sure how this would impact cordova rendered pages

Comment: Interesting idea. I will investigate and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into it and when I log out the current context and the list of contexts on the iOS version of the app, I see: currentContext:  NATIVE_APP
contexts:  [ 'NATIVE_APP' ] So basically there is only one context. This may be different for Android though.

Comment: I have to do this exact same thing in a few days. Let me try this in a few days and report back here

Comment: Thanks for following up. Our interim solution is probably going to be to use Protractor to test at least basic mobile functionality through Chrome, although I would like to be able to use Appium for correctness and for testing any Cordova plugin integration. Would be interested to hear what you find. Thanks again!

Comment: How about this - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/361 they seem to have figured things out with protractor?

Comment: Thank you for investigating this further. The problem I am running into is not that I cannot get Protractor hitting a Cordova-built iOS / Android app (what I think the posters in that issue were saying). The issue I am having is that when I do connect in Protractor/Appium, I have no useful handles to make assertions with (on text elements, etc.)